# How do I make my site show a favicon in the bookmark toolbar in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, favicon

None of these seem to work. It works for tabs, but not bookmarks bar

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon/favicon-196x196.png" />
<link rel="image/x-icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon/favicon-196x196.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon/favicon-16x16.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute path instead of relative path.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />`

Comment: does it have to be a `.ico` file? I'm trying to use a `.png`....absolute url doesn't work with `.png`

Comment: @chovy no it doesn't have to be a `.ico` file. Try hard refreshing your browser. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: its not. it doesn't work. its a known issue with firefox for like 10 years. there are dozens of open bugs about it. But some sites actually have a favicon on the bookmarks bar. Mine doesn't.